# OpenId + Jwt Bearer with ASP.NET Core: The signature is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openid, google-openid, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to integrate openid with JWT Bearer middleware in my asp.net core project.

Here is my startup code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                ClientId = "<my-client-id>",
                ClientSecret = "<my-client-secret>",
                Authority = "https://accounts.google.com",
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                CallbackPath = "/api/home/redirect",
                Scope = { "email", "openid", "profile"},
                SignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
            });


            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

When I send request to api/home (This request requires authentication), it throws me an error response:

**WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"**

What am I missing. 
Could anyone help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: so are using your google account as your login and  you are using google as your Authority if I see that correctly, are you using openiddict? where is your TokenPath?  How are you getting an Access_Token to use with Bearer call to the site?

Comment: Yes, im using google as my token provider. Could you show how my code should be, please

Comment: well I use IdentityServer4, middleware plug for asp.core it works exactly like that but my database uses registered users on the database to authenticate, now you can set it up so that it will add their identity from google / twitter / ms account etc, as an external login provider.  Where my site is the authority.  How are you calling the API in your project?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean about how I call my api in my project. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: `https://www.yoursite.com/api/home`  now how did you get the token that is in the Authorization header....  `Authorization : Bearer <SOMETOKEN>` the some token where did you get it to include in the GET call to `https://www.yoursite.com/api/home`?

Comment: What I have implemented is : I specify a route , such as : api/account/authorize to obtain username & password, make request to Google OAuth2 and exchange for the access_token, after receiving access_token returned from Google OAuth2 service, I pass it directly to client. Now, I'm trying to configure OpenId Connect to see whether it can help me reduce that step or not.

Comment: I've got the same issue with a KeyCloak based token which is RSA signed.